# I cannot decode emojis stored in mysql database

Tags: php, node.js, html-entities, html-encode, htmldecode

I am using [ent package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ent)  for Encode and decode HTML entities in one of my nodejs project. An example conversion is given below

```
var ent          = require('ent'); 
let encodeString = ent.encode( 'Lorem Ipsum  Dolor 542  O’ipsum for ❤️ dummy' ) ;
encodeString give result as  Lorem Ipsum &#128690; Dolor 542  O&#8217;ipsum for &#10084;&#65039; dummy
```

But I cannot reproduce the same result when I tried in php, Code is give below

```
$string = addslashes(trim(htmlentities('Lorem Ipsum  Dolor 542  O’ipsum for ❤️ dummy', ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")))
Result:   Lorem Ipsum  Dolor 542  O&rsquo;ipsum for ❤️ dummy
Expected: Lorem Ipsum &#128690; Dolor 542  O&#8217;ipsum for &#10084;&#65039; dummy
```

Someone please help me to achive the same result in php same as the one obtained from nodejs ent.encode

Note: DB collation as utf8mb4_unicode_ci and saving without encode doesn't work for some emoji's. I found that If I could save date in php as `Lorem Ipsum &#128690; Dolor 542  O&#8217;ipsum for &#10084;&#65039; dummy` It will work correctly.

Comment: What particular problem does this difference make?

Comment: @YourCommonSense  If the data is save as `Lorem Ipsum &#128690; Dolor 542  O&#8217;ipsum for &#10084;&#65039; dummy` in my mysql database, Then only I can decode it correctly on both php and nodejs front end's . SO I am expecting a php encode solution equivalent to ent.encode function

Comment: 1. Use `utf8mb4` charset for both tables and connection. 2. DO NOT use any html encoding for database interactions

Comment: @YourCommonSense I tried that also, But the cycle symbol doesn't work , Conclusion I found is If I could save date in php as `Lorem Ipsum &#128690; Dolor 542  O&#8217;ipsum for &#10084;&#65039; dummy`  It will work correctly.

Comment: Well you "tried" it wrong. You must use utf8mb4 charset for both tables and connection

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks it works when I use `utf8mb4` in connections
But is there a solution in php ? That will be good as there is already encoded data exists in the database and the db is large

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254396/discussion-between-ajith-and-your-common-sense).

Comment: You don't need to encode or decode emojis, consider them as characters and display them as they are.